# Which is the best custom error message system to use in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an MVC3 project.  I have a controller where I do some error checking.  This part is working to the point where I apply the various constraints to user input.  Unfortunately, I can't use javascript as an id is not assigned until after the user submits the form.

This id is crucial to error checking so I've done this in the controller.

So, as each error occurs, I form a error message that i want to pass to the view.  The view is strongly typed to an entity.

My question is which choice should I use?  ViewState, View Bag , TempData or ModelState?

Essentially, I have a prepared error message that I want to display in an asp:Label in my view.  So far, I've tried:

```
ViewBag.ErrMsg = "The client must be over 18 to open a TFSA.";
```

and then in my view

```
 <% if (ViewBag.ErrMsg != "")
           { %>
       <div class="errorMsg"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%ViewBag.ErrMsg %>" ></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

But obviously just returns whatever is between the quotes, which is <%ViewBag.ErrMsg %>.

Can someone help?

Comment: `asp:Label` and `runat="server"` are typically frowned upon in asp.net-mvc.  Why are you using webform *controls* in an MVC application?

Comment: Yes, I know.  I don't have control over that (pardon the pun!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty but it 'works':

```
 if (CreateFlag == false)
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "The client must be over 18 to perform this action.";
                return RedirectToAction("DrinkCreate", "Drink");
            }
```

and in the view:

```
 <% if (TempData.ContainsKey("ErrorMessage"))
           { %>
                <div class="errorMsg"><%= TempData["ErrorMessage"] %></div>        
        <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to validate your model, so to my mind it is natural to use ModelState as it was designed specifically for that purpose.

The first thing you should do is create a `buddy class` for your entity. This object extends your Entity Framework entity by adding metadata, so that if you ever need to regenerate your entity, your customizations won't be lost. So, if your entity is called `Client`, you'd have something like this:

```
 //This extends the Entity Framework entity thanks to the `partial` keyword
 [MetadataType(typeof(ClientMetadata))]
 public partial class Client { }

 //This class applies metadata through data annotations that validates your model
 public partial class ClientMetadata{
     //Let's say we want to add a couple validation rule to the client's age 
     [Required(ErrorMessage="Age is required")]
     [Range(19,100,ErrorMessage="Your age must be between 19 and 100")] 
     public int Age { get;set; }
 }
```

Now that `Client` has been extended with a buddy class, ModelState validation automatically kicks in. In your controller's action, you'd typically have something like:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Update(Client client){
      //During model binding, validation is performed on client
      if(!ModelState.IsValid){
           return View(client);
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

If you have validation errors, then you could surface them using the ValidationSummary in your view, which prints all errors to a list:

```
  @Html.ValidationSummary()
```

This example veers slightly away from your use case, as to use the built in `RangeAttribute` data annotation, I supplied a max number for age, as there is no baked-in data annotation for a min value. Let me know if you need one and I'll show you how. I'm in a hostel in Peru right now and I'm riffing off the top of my head as the internet here isn't very good and I'm on my netbook without my old projects :)

Comment: Thanks Chris. This would be excellent if we were rewriting the app but, unfortunately, we don't have that luxury.  I have the logic done in the controller already.  Basically, all I want to do is grab the error messages from the controller and display it in my view.  We're not using Razor, hence the use of <% %> in my original post.

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand the constraints you have. If you can't use Razor, you can still use the ValidationSummary object. What parts are you unable to touch? Are you unable to create buddy classes? Data annotations really are the ideal way to validate, and violating in your controller violates the concept of single responsibility.